# How to find the N smallest values in a 2 dimensional array (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, graph-algorithm

Hello I am currently wrtiting a program to calculate the stability of hydrogen bond configuration in a solvent. 
The problem is at the moment I have choosen to make 2 dimensional array with the distance between two molecules i & j. 
How do I find the N (given) smallest values in that array for a given i without losing the indices while sorting. 
Is there something like this in a standard library, I first thought of using  std::min but that did not work out.

EDIT:
Where MAXBONDS is the N i mentionned above.
The class is

```
class item{ // ITEM the molecule itself
private:
            //part for molecule charazerization

    std::vector<double> coordinates;
    std::vector<int> bondings;
public:
double calculateSolvents(double dist[][], std::vector<item> items);
}



double item::calculateSolvents(double dist[][], std::vector<item> items){  
for(int i=0; i <= items.size()-1;i++){
  if(items[i].bondings.size()<MAXBONDS){
  for(int j=0;j<= items.size()-1 ;j++){
      if(items[j].bondings.size()< MAXBONDS && 
        (find(items[i].bondings.begin(),items[i].bondings.end(),j)==items[i].bondings.end()) &&
        (find(items[j].bondings.begin(),items[j].bondings.end(),i)==items[j].bondings.end())){


  }}
  }}
```

And the instances of the class are stored in a vector

```
 std::vector<item> items
```

And yes i mean for a given i, I want the N (MAXBONDS) smallest values for all possible j's.

EDIT2:
This is acutally a graph algorithm problem
dist[][] represents the distance between molecule i and j. I need (like in a TSP problem) the overall shortest path between all molecules(and i need to know wich molecule is connected to which). And every molecule should have MAXBONDS connection th others(they actually also have lay within a maximum distance but I already accounted for that in the dist array) so my greedy approach is to take the N(MAXBONDS) shortest distances for all possible j for a given i form the array dist.

Comment: Show us some code please. What do i and j stand for?

Comment: you mean for a given i, you want to find n smallest values for all possible j's??

Comment: I edited the question hope things are more clear now
Tank you

Comment: I'm sorry, that is still illegible to me, perhaps I lack the chemistry knowledge about stability of hydrogen bonds in a solvent. On the (very likely) chance that other people here share the same limitations (as this is a programming site), can you please explain further? Why is dist a two dimensional array? Distance from what? What do items represent in that function? And most importantly, what do you mean by "getting N smallest values of an array without losing indices while sorting"?

Comment: So I hope it's clear now (see EDIT2), you can actually see it as grah algoritm problem.
where every node has to have  N edges that have and the be as short as possible.

Comment: If N is significantly smaller than the total number of elements to be searched, then it is best to use a priority queue of size N, using the reverse of the desired ordering.  Form the queue with the first N elements with worst of those N exposed.  For each element beyond the first N, if that element is better than worst in the queue substitute it into the queue.

Comment: You seem to be worrying more about the strategy for representing information during the search.  That is something that should be done correctly, but shouldn't be hard.  A pair or struct of the `i,j` coordinates of an element is the minimal representation, then the compare operation and the location of the 2-d array can be bound together into a functor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer would you mind giving me a code example that does makes a priority queue with a class i can't find one.

Comment: Isn't distance a single double value that can be calculated from the coordinates of both molecules? Why do you even need dist array? Where do the bonds of a molecule come into play? Shouldn't they be a vector<item> in your item class?

Comment: First yes. Second because when i was writing the algorithm I thought it would be a good idea which it was not (excuse me I'm new to programming in chemiinformatics or informatics at all especially c++). Third, for the further processing of the data it is necesarry to know to which molecules (nodes) are bonded (edges). I thought I'd be able to do that with the bondings vector that contains the index of the molecules it is bonded to. I actually tried to do it with a costum priority queue but it did not work due to (to me inexplicable) compilation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm giving you an algorithm to find out the N nearest neighbours given a matrix of distances. I'll make no further guesses about your modelization of the molecules compound, so I'm using a very simplified approach.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <limits>

struct Point3D {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

double squareDistance(const Point3D &a, const Point3D &b) {
    double dx = a.x - b.x;
    double dy = a.y - b.y;
    double dz = a.z - b.z;
    return dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz;
}

struct Molecule {
    // more meaningfull stuff omitted 
    // ...
    Point3D _pos;
};
```

I'm using a map to store the index of the molecule j and the distance from molecule i.

```
#define MAX_NEIGHBOUR 4 

struct Neighbours {
    std::map<double,size_t> _n;
    double _limit;

    Neighbours() : _limit(std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()) {}

    double add(double dd, size_t index) {
        if (dd <= _limit) {     // update neighbours only when necessary
            _n[dd] = index;
            if ( _n.size() > MAX_NEIGHBOUR ) {
                auto itn = _n.end();
                _n.erase(--itn);
                if ( dd < _limit ) _limit = dd;
            }
        }
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & out, const Neighbours & nn) {
        for ( auto i : nn._n) {
            out << i.second << " at " << std::sqrt(i.first) << ", ";
        }
        return out << std::endl;
    }
};
```

I assume that the matrix of distances is simmetrical (unless you are using same weird topology) and I store it in a single vector.

```
struct DistMol {
    DistMol(const std::vector<Molecule> & mols) :   _rows(mols.size()),
                                                    _d(_rows*(_rows-1)/2+1),
                                                    _near(_rows),
                                                    _mol(mols){}

    void evaluate() {       // The "matrix" of distances is simmetric
        auto id = _d.begin();
        for (size_t i=0; i<_rows; i++) {
            for (size_t j=i+1; j<_rows; j++) {
                *id = squareDistance(_mol[i]._pos,_mol[j]._pos);
                _near[i].add(*id,j);
                _near[j].add(*id,i);
                ++id;
            }
        }
    }

    double distance(size_t i, size_t j) { // remember that I have only half the matrix
        long int dij = i - j;

        if ( dij > 0 && i < _rows ) 
            return std::sqrt(_d[j*_rows - j*(j+1)/2 + dij - 1]);
        else if ( dij < 0 && j < _rows)
            return std::sqrt(_d[i*_rows - i*(i+1)/2 - dij - 1]);
        else return 0.0;
    }
    void showDistances() {
        std::cout << std::fixed;
        for ( size_t i=0; i<_rows; i++) {
            for (size_t j=0; j<_rows; j++) {
                std::cout << distance(i,j) << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
    void showNearest() {
        size_t i = 0;
        for ( auto n : _near) {
            std::cout << i++ << ": " << n;
        }
    }

    size_t _rows;
    std::vector<double> _d;
    std::vector<Neighbours> _near;
    const std::vector<Molecule> & _mol;
};
```

This is an example of use and its output:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<Molecule> mo   {{1.0,0.0,0.5}, {2.0,0.5,1.2}, {4.8,2.3,1.9},
                                {3.7,3.9,8.7}, {2.1,0.5,1.3}, {5.8,2.5,4.4},
                                {5.7,4.1,2.3}, {1.7,0.8,6.2}, {0.8,0.3,1.0}};
    DistMol dm {mo};

    dm.evaluate();
    dm.showDistances();
    dm.showNearest();

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
0.000000 1.319091 4.657252 9.473120 1.449138 6.670832 6.491533 5.798276 0.616441 
1.319091 0.000000 3.401470 8.408329 0.141421 5.355371 5.278257 5.017968 1.232883 
4.657252 3.401470 0.000000 7.071775 3.300000 2.700000 2.051828 5.509083 4.561798 
9.473120 8.408329 7.071775 0.000000 8.299398 4.985980 6.708204 4.456456 8.981091 
1.449138 0.141421 3.300000 8.299398 0.000000 5.224940 5.188449 4.925444 1.349074 
6.670832 5.355371 2.700000 4.985980 5.224940 0.000000 2.641969 4.789572 6.434283 
6.491533 5.278257 2.051828 6.708204 5.188449 2.641969 0.000000 6.488451 6.335614 
5.798276 5.017968 5.509083 4.456456 4.925444 4.789572 6.488451 0.000000 5.300943 
0.616441 1.232883 4.561798 8.981091 1.349074 6.434283 6.335614 5.300943 0.000000 
0: 8 at 0.616441, 1 at 1.319091, 4 at 1.449138, 2 at 4.657252, 
1: 4 at 0.141421, 8 at 1.232883, 0 at 1.319091, 2 at 3.401470, 
2: 6 at 2.051828, 5 at 2.700000, 4 at 3.300000, 1 at 3.401470, 
3: 7 at 4.456456, 5 at 4.985980, 2 at 7.071775, 4 at 8.299398, 
4: 1 at 0.141421, 8 at 1.349074, 0 at 1.449138, 2 at 3.300000, 
5: 6 at 2.641969, 2 at 2.700000, 3 at 4.985980, 4 at 5.224940, 
6: 2 at 2.051828, 5 at 2.641969, 4 at 5.188449, 1 at 5.278257, 
7: 3 at 4.456456, 5 at 4.789572, 4 at 4.925444, 1 at 5.017968, 
8: 0 at 0.616441, 1 at 1.232883, 4 at 1.349074, 2 at 4.561798,
```